# Combining scenekit and spritekit in a single screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

Apologies if this is a newbie question, i'm still trying to find my way around Swift and SpriteKit / SceneKit.

Is it possible to combine SpriteKit and SceneKit in a single view, e.g. using SpriteKit to render a map in portion of the screen while using SceneKit to render the main 3D view?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can and it was shown in various demos at WWDC.
Take a look at the `overlaySKScene` property of `SCNSceneRenderer`.

Comment: I heard somewhere, probably WWDC, that the other way around - draw SceneKit on top of SpriteKit - should be possible but have yet to find some hard facts. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

One way of using `SpriteKit` within `SceneKit` is as follows:

```
SCNView *sceneView = [[SCNView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] options:@{@"SCNPreferredRenderingAPIKey": @(SCNRenderingAPIOpenGLES3)}];
[self.view addSubview:sceneView];
sceneView.scene = [SCNScene scene];

// ... whatever else you're doing

SKContainerOverlay *skOverlay = [[SKContainerOverlay alloc] initWithSize:self.sceneView.bounds.size];
skOverlay.delegate = self;    
self.sceneView.overlaySKScene = skOverlay; // the key to your question
self.sceneView.overlaySKScene.hidden = NO;
self.sceneView.overlaySKScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;
```